# Can Bluefoot be extended/customized?

Tags: magento2, bluefootcms

Is there currently anyway to extend bluefoot functionality ([bluefoot](https://www.bluefootcms.com/))? I found that its vendor folder is located at `vendor/gene/bluefoot`. Let's say I wanted to add another tab to the panel on the right of the wysiwyg.

If it can be extended, could I do it inside my custom theme like I would extend core magento modules? Or would it have to be altered inside the vendor folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento modules can be used from `app/code/*` and from `vendor` directory, which used by `composer`.

In order to understand whether the package is a `magento` module, find in the root of the package the file `registration.php`.

If file exist and contains code like

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_ModuleName',
    __DIR__ );
```

then it is magento module and you can use default ways (applicable to any core module) for customization (including using custom theme).

---

For component registration in composer package can be used files with other name (not `registration.php`). For get used file you can look at `composer.json` section `autoload/files`

```
"autoload": {
        "files": [ "mycustomfilename.php" ],
}
```

Comment: So theoretically, if I create a folder at `app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/Theme/Gene_Bluefoot` that should be the right location?

Answer (score 2):

Extends Bluefoot Module in your custom Theme.

> app/design/frontend/Theme_namespace/Your_theme/**Gene_BlueFoot**

Change: Gene_Bluefoot -> Gene_BlueFoot